# setstate then response in rest api react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make the state isLoading changed to true when `recentTransactionsRecipient` and `recentTransactionsSender` is not null.

I would like to do a promise, then

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.Auth.recentTransactionsRecipient(this.props.id)
      .then(res => {
        if (res) {
          this.setState({
            recentTransactionsRecipient: res,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        /* just ignore */
      });

    this.Auth.recentTransactionsSender(this.props.id)
      .then(res => {
        if (res) {
          this.setState({
            recentTransactionsSender: res,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        /* just ignore */
      });
  }
```

Comment: Does it need to run in parallel? Otherwise you could just return the `this.Auth.recentTransactionSender(this.props.id)` in the first then block. Then you can use `.then` to receive the second response. Otherwise store both requests in an array and use `Promise.all` as @mehamasum already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Promise.all()`. [See MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  this.setState({
    recentTransactionsRecipient: values[0],
    recentTransactionsSender: values[1],
    isLoading: false
  });
});
```

Comment: @ReactRouter4 Did you require the `.catch(() => { /* just ignore */  })` behavior to work in the same way as your original post?

Answer (score 0):

The use of [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would work well here as it allows you to reduce multiple input promises into a single promise. The single promise returned by `Promise.all()` is where you would implement the `isLoading : true` state update logic for your component.

An important detail to note with this; Given your code requires any errors in `Auth` to be ignored (coupled with the behavior of `Promise.all()` [to `reject` if any promise passed to it is rejected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Description)), you will need to account for this in your code.

One possibility is to introduce a helper function that would "absorb" a rejected promise so that the rejected promise isn't propagated to `Promise.all()` (which would cause your subsequent `setState()` to be skipped):

```js
componentDidMount() {
    
    /*
    Locally defined helper method to absorb failure/rejection of the supplied promise
    */
    const ignoreIfRejected = (promise) => {
      
      return promise().catch(() => {
        console.info('A promise failed. Ignoring.');
      });
    }
    
    /* 
    The Promise returned from Promise.all will reject if any one of the promises in
    the passed array fails. Wrap each promise in locally defined ignoreIfRejected()
    helper to "absorb" any such error 
    */
    Promise.all([
      ignoreIfRejected(this.Auth.recentTransactionsRecipient(this.props.id)),
      ignoreIfRejected(this.Auth.recentTransactionsSender(this.props.id))
    ])
    .then((recipient, sender) => {
      
      if( recipient !== null && sender !== null) {
        
        /* 
        If resolved response from both promises returns non-null value
        then set isLoading state to true as required in post 
        */
        this.setState({ 
          recentTransactionsSender : sender,
          recentTransactionsRecipient : recipient,
          isLoading : false 
        });
      }      
    });
  }
```